# cvsnakeimage in opencv2.2

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use the cvsnakeimage function for active contours from opencv.

The problem is that i cannot find this function under opencv2.2, have the name been changed or what is the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `cvSnakeImage` reside in `legacy` module. (`opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp` at line 818)

```
/* Updates active contour in order to minimize its cummulative
   (internal and external) energy. */
CVAPI(void)  cvSnakeImage( const IplImage* image, CvPoint* points,
                           int  length, float* alpha,
                           float* beta, float* gamma,
                           int coeff_usage, CvSize  win,
                           CvTermCriteria criteria, int calc_gradient CV_DEFAULT(1));
```

Comment: You need to link your application with `opencv_legacy220.lib` (`opencv_legacy220d.lib` for debug version)

Comment: You can easily pass `cv::Mat` to `cvSnakeImage` function because `cv::Mat` class implements an `operator IplImage()`. C++ version of this function does not exist and I think it will not be added in future because `cvSnakeImage` is placed in `legacy` module.

Comment: :: Can you answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432797/cvsnakeimage-opencv-api-example-documentation) ?

Comment: @AndreyKamaev Is there a replacement for cvSnakeImage in OpenCV 3?