# cvSnakeImage() OpenCV API example/documentation

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection

**Can anyone refer me any tutorial/documentation on how to use cvSnakeImage().**

I have refered [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/video_motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#snakeimage) link but example has not been provided.

I want to use this cvSnakeImage() to perfrom Active contour model on an image.

[image]

The image is of eye after thresholding and the black thing is eye pupil. I want to detect (draw circle) eye pupil in this image using **cvSnakeImage()** (sort of constraint, I have to use this function only).

C++ platform

**Can anyone refer me any tutorial/documentation on how to use cvSnakeImage().**

Comment: Can anyone kindly help me... If any information missing in the question to answer ... I can edit the question to give more info...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A link to C++ example:

- [C++ Sample Code](http://download.andol.info/cvsnakeimage.cpp)

Comment: probably a *bad* idea to edit outdated questions about legacy code, that won't be there in a few weeks(3.0)

Comment: @berak What do you mean? I know it could be controversial but I clicked on it and nothing happened.  Could you please explain why you would keep a dead link?

Comment: willowgarage is dead. cvSnakeImage is dead. the c-api is dead. opencv is at itseez.org now, here are the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/)

Comment: just leave anything, that has iplimages in it, under a big rock. please.

Comment: @berak You have got enough reps? Put it back if you think it was wrong.

Comment: i don't understand you. put *what* back *where* ?

Comment: @berak All I'm saying that you can look at the revisions and roll back if you think the edit was wrong. I did what I thought was right. You have got more reps that me so feel free to revert if you think that is a better approach. I have no issues with that.

Comment: The question is specifically about cvSnakeImage and using cvSnakeImage so your comments about it being deprecated are correct, but will not help in answering this question. However since the other link was dead, it makes sense to remove it.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a replacement active contours method in OpenCV 3?