# apply the edge detection in an image segmentation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I have two questions about snake edge detection.
The first question is, in openCV there is a function cvSnakeImage(src,points,.......), what does the points parameter mean?

The second questions is: I want to  apply this function on the part surrounded by an edge that I have already made, how can I do this?

This is my code for edge detection:

```
cvCanny(img_bw, img_canny , thresh, thresh * 50, 3);

cvFindContours(img_canny, contour, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_TREE,    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: Are you sure that function still supported by ocv? this is a [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432797/cvsnakeimage-opencv-api-example-documentation) question

Comment: cvSnakeImage was moved to legacy. and you should no more use the arcane c-api. please , buckle up!

Comment: yes , it is supported .                                      [link](https://fossies.org/dox/opencv-2.4.8/snakes_8cpp.html)

Answer (score 0):

points parameter is the pointer to the snakes point array

https://fossies.org/dox/opencv-2.4.8/snakes_8cpp_source.html

Here is an example of how to use snakes

http://download.andol.info/cvsnakeimage.cpp